# crash en acumulador de un vector?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

estoy empezando hace poco en programacion y tengo que hacer un trabajo de un juego de dados , el problema es que cuando quiero hacer un acumulador para saber cuantas veces se repite cada numero me creshea o reporta numeros falsos[image: el "dad" es un vector de 5 con numeros aleatorios y el "acum" es otro vector de 5 relleno de ceros]
[image: esta es la funcion que intento usar en el la primera imagen]

[image: y estas dos son las otras dos funciones que se me ocurrieron para esto , pero sigo con el mismo problema]

se que debe ser algo muy chico en lo que me estoy confundiendo , pero llevo 2 dias intentando que el acumulador me de bien , si alguno puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

```
     int unjugador(char nombre[420]) {
     int dad[5] , i , j , temp , vectorpospunt[9] , punt=0 , nr=1 , puntp=0 
     , acum[5] , dec , posj ;

     while (punt<10000){


     for (i=0; i<6; i++){
     acum[i]=0;
     }
     puntp=0;
     posj=99;


     cout << "RONDA NRO :" <<nr << endl;

     tirardados(dad);
     ///truchardados(dad);
     mostrardados(dad);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     for(int j=i+1;j<=5;j++){
        if(dad[i]>dad[j]){cout << "acumulador de 1 es : " << acum[0] << endl 
    ;
         temp=dad[j];
         dad[j]=dad[i];
         dad[i]=temp;
        }
     }
     }

     ///acumulardados(acum, dad);

    /**for(i=0;i<6;i++){

    acum[i]=contarnumeros(dad, i+1);

    }**/

    acumulardadosdos(dad , acum );

    cout << "acumulador de 1 es : " << acum[0] << endl ;
    cout << "acumulador de 2 es : " << acum[1] << endl ;
    cout << "acumulador de 3 es : " << acum[2] << endl ;
    cout << "acumulador de 4 es : " << acum[3] << endl ;
    cout << "acumulador de 5 es : " << acum[4] << endl ;
    cout << "acumulador de 6 es : " << acum[5] << endl ;
    }
```

y las funciones que probe para los acumuladores son :

```
void acumulardados(int acum[] , int dad[]){
int i , j;
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
for(j=0;j<6;j++){
    if(dad[j]==i+1){
        acum[i]++;
    }
}
} 
}

int contarnumeros(int v[], int valorAbuscar){
int i, cantidad=0;
for (i=0;i<6 ;i++ )
{
if (v[i]==valorAbuscar)cantidad++;
}
return cantidad;
}


void acumulardadosdos(int dad[] , int acum[]){
int i ;
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
if (dad[i]==1){
        acum[0]++;
}else if (dad[i]==2){
acum[1]++;
}else if (dad[i]==3){
acum[2]++;
}else if (dad[i]==4){
acum[3]++;
}else if (dad[i]==5){
acum[4]++;
}else {
acum[5]++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código a tu pregunta. Recuerda darle formato adecuado, seleccionándolo y oprimiendo el botón `{ }`. Te invito a revisar [porque una captura de tu código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868#2869).

Comment: @toledano ahi estan agregados todos los codigos necesarios

Comment: Nunca, **nunca**, ***NUNCA***, ***nunca***, nunca jamás compartas tu código como capturas de pantalla, las capturas de pantalla no se pueden compilar.

Answer (score 0):

#### El problema.

Tu problema parece ser el desconocimiento del funcionamiento de los arreglos de C++ y los bucles `for` de C++. Declaras un arreglo de 5 elementos:

```
//  vvvvvv <--- 5 elementos: dad[0], dad[1], dad[2], dad[3] y dad[4].
int dad[5] , i , j , temp , vectorpospunt[9] , punt=0 , nr=1 , puntp=0 
 , acum[5] , dec , posj ;
```

Y recorres los 6 primeros elementos:

```
//       vvv <--- 6 elementos: i = 0, i = 1, i = 2, i = 3, i = 4 e i = 5.
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
    // ...
}
```

#### El error.

Acceder mediante punteros a memoria fuera del ámbito de un arreglo es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), esto significa que podría pasar cualquier cosa, desde un fallo en tiempo de ejecución a que [tus fosas nasales expulsasen demonios](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon#English).

Cuando tu bucle alcanza el índice `5`, estás accediendo a la sexta posición de tu arreglo `dad` y esto es una posición más allá del tamaño de dicho arreglo, por lo tanto obtienes el comportamiento indefinido.

#### Propuesta.

Salvo el uso de `std::cout`, no hay nada en tu código que haga pensar que estás trabajando en C++, mi propuesta es que uses las herramientas de C++ para mejorar tu código:

- Usa `std::string`, no `char[240]`, te dará menos problemas.

  ```
  int unjugador(const std::string &nombre) {
  //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Mas facil de usar.
  ```
- Inicializa automáticamente tus arreglos, no manualmente.

  ```
  // Anyadiendo {} al final de un arreglo este se inicializa a 0 automaticamente
  int dad[5]{} , i , j , temp , vectorpospunt[9]{}, punt=0 , nr=1 , puntp=0, acum[5]{}, dec , posj ;
  //        ~~                                  ~~                                  ~~
  ```
- Si vas a pasar arreglos como parámetro, usa referencias a arreglo o referencias a `std::array` (recuerda marcarlas como constantes si no van a ser modificadas):

  ```
  //                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvv, vvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- Referencia a arreglo de 5 int
  void acumulardados(int (&acum)[5], int (&dad)[5]){
      // ...
  }

  //                vvvvvvvvvvv <--- Referencia a arreglo de 5 int
  int contarnumeros(int (&v)[5], int valorAbuscar){
      // ...
  }

  //                    vvvvvvvvvvvvv, vvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- Referencia a arreglo de 5 int
  void acumulardadosdos(int (&dad)[5], int (&acum)[5]){
      // ...
  }
  ```

  ```
  using int5 = std::array<int, 5>;
  //                 vvvvvvvvvv, vvvvvvvv <--- Referencia a array de 5 int
  void acumulardados(int5 &acum, int5 dad){
      // ...
  }

  //                vvvvvvv <--- Referencia a array de 5 int
  int contarnumeros(int5 &v, int valorAbuscar){
      // ...
  }

  //                    vvvvvvvvv, vvvvvvvvvv <--- Referencia a array de 5 int
  void acumulardadosdos(int5 &dad, int5 &acum){
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Cumpliendo con el anterior punto, tus bucles no volverán a tener problemas de índices si usas el `for` de rango:

  ```
  for (auto &d : dad){
      if (d==1){
          // ...
      }
   }
  ```
- Usa un mapa para contar acumulaciones:

  ```
  using int5 = std::array<int, 5>;
  using acumulaciones = std::map<int, int>;

  void acumulardadosdos(const int5 &dad , acumulaciones &acum){
      for (const auto &d : dad){
          auto [iterador, insertado] = acum.insert({d, 0});
          ++iterador->second;
      }
  }
  ```